# pgfkeys: Dynamic definition of keys

Tags: pgfkeys, scoping

I want to define a list of keynames in a macro.
Then I want to initialize multiple keys with this keynames.

I've tried with `\foreach`, also with `.list` but the keys are never defined.

But, nothing it's easy:-) .

Someone can guide to the solution?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

%%%%%%  COMMAND: IMPORTANT!

%%%%% Definition of Schema 
\newcommand{\initSLR}[1][]{
    \pgfkeys{sch/.store in={\commentSch}, %%%%%% Here the schema is stored in \commentSch
        #1,
    }
}
%%%%% Load Key Values
\newcommand{\paperComment}[2][]{%                Working but it isn't dynamic
    \pgfkeys{
        /paperComment/#2/.initial={},
        /paperComment/#2/.cd,
        Cons/.initial={},                             %%% I want dynamic initiation
        Pros/.initial={},                             %%% I want dynamic initiation
        Comments/.initial={},                         %%% I want dynamic initiation
        Focus/.initial={},                            %%% I want dynamic initiation
        Examples/.initial={},                         %%% I want dynamic initiation
        Motivation/.initial={},                       %%% I want dynamic initiation
        #1,
    }             
}

\newcommand{\NotWorkPaperComment}[2][]{%                           %%%% Not working
\pgfkeys{/paperComment/#2/.initial={}}
\foreach \x in \commentSch
{
    \typeout{Init \x }
    \pgfkeys{/paperComment/#2/\x/.initial={}}
}
\pgfkeys{/paperComment/#2/.cd,
    #1,
}             
}

\newcommand{\NotWorkPaperCommentTwo}[2][]{           %%%% Not working
\pgfkeys{/paperComment/#2/.initial={},}
\pgfkeys{/paperComment/#2/.cd,
    define/.code={\pgfkeysalso{#2/##1/.initial={}}},
    define/.list=\commentSch,
    #1,
}             
}

%%% Print Loaded values
\newcommand{\printSection}[2][]{
    \paragraph{#1} \hfill

        \pgfkeysvalueof{/paperComment/#2/#1} \par
}

\begin{document}

\initSLR[sch={Comments,Examples,Pros,Cons,Motivation,Focus}]

\section{The Schema is in the correct command}

\commentSch

\section{Expected Usage}
%%% Load Values
%%%% Comment this section and uncomment one of next two to see ...
\paperComment[Pros={The pros of pgfkeysWorksOrNot},
    Cons={The Cons of pgfkeysWorksOrNot}
]{pgfkeysWorksOrNot}

% \NotWorkPaperCommentTwo[Pros={The pros of pgfkeysToNotWork},
%     Cons={The cons of pgfkeysToNotWork}
% ]{pgfkeysToNotWork}

% \NotWorkPaperComment[Pros={The pros of pgfkeysToNotWork},
%     Cons={The cons of pgfkeysToNotWork}
% ]{pgfkeysToNotWork}

\section{Static is Working}
\printSection[Cons]{pgfkeysWorksOrNot}
\printSection[Pros]{pgfkeysWorksOrNot}

\section{Dynamic is not Working}
%\printSection[Cons]{pgfkeysToNotWork}
%\printSection[Pros]{pgfkeysToNotWork}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to `\usepackage{pgffor}` to use `\foreach`. However, this will not work, since `pgfkeys` only works on local scales, and `\foreach` groups every iteration.

Comment: Also, your current `\initSLR` is overly complex. You could as well just do `\newcommand*\commentSch{}` and `\newcommand\initSLR[1][]{\edef\commentSch{\unexpanded{#1}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to expand (at least once) `\commentSch` before you hand it over to `.list`, otherwise you just do

```
\foreach \element in {\commentSch}
```

which is just one element: `\commentSch`.

Thus, you need to do

```
define/.list/.expand once=\commentSch
% or
define/.list/.expanded=\commentSch
```

---

Though, it is hard to follow what is actually happening in your document.

In the code below, there are three commands defined:

1. `\papercommentSetSubsections` that store the list of subsections.
2. `\papercommentNewSection` which initializes the subsections as per above and then applies the specified values.
3. `\papercommentPrintSection`, as above but puts the values on the page.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys, pgffor}
\newcommand*\papercommentset{\pgfqkeys{/paperComment}}
\papercommentset{
  @/subsections/.initial=,
  @/create section/.style={
    /utils/temp/.style={#1/##1/.initial=},
    /utils/temp/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/paperComment/@/subsections},
    #1/.cd
  }
}
\newcommand*\papercommentSetSubsections[1]{%
  \papercommentset{@/subsections={#1}}%
}
\newcommand*\papercommentNewSection[2]{%
  \papercommentset{@/create section={#2},#1}%
}
\newcommand*\papercommentPrintSection[2]{%
  \paragraph{#1}\hfill\par
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/paperComment/#2/#1}\par
}
\begin{document}
\papercommentSetSubsections{
  Comments, Examples, Pros, Cons, Motivation, Focus}
\papercommentNewSection{
  Pros={The pros of pgfkeysToNotWork},
  Cons={The cons of pgfkeysToNotWork}
}{pgfkeysToNotWork}

\papercommentPrintSection{Pros}{pgfkeysToNotWork}
\papercommentPrintSection{Cons}{pgfkeysToNotWork}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following borrows `\clist_map_inline:nn` from `expl3`. That is a loop over comma separated values that doesn't use groups, so it's usable for your use case (unlike `\foreach`). Since we want to loop over the contents of a macro (which isn't yet sanitised by `expl3`) we generate a variant of `\clist_map_inline:nn` that will expand our macro for us.

Also, I've cleaned up your code a bit (put `%` at the end of lines to suppress spurious spaces, used `\pgfqkeys` instead of `\pgfkeys` for a small speed up).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

%%%%%%  COMMAND: IMPORTANT!

%%%%% Definition of Schema 
\newcommand{\initSLR}[1][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/paperComment-sch}{sch/.store in={\commentSch},#1}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% generate a new variant which will expand the macro \commentSch once for us.
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn { o }
% get a new name for this so we can use it outside of ExplSyntaxOn...Off
\cs_new_eq:NN \clistloop \clist_map_inline:on
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\PaperComment}[2][]{%
  \pgfqkeys{/paperComment}{#2/.initial={}}%
  % in this loop, we don't use \x for the value, but ##1
  \clistloop\commentSch
    {%
      \typeout{Init ##1}%
      \pgfqkeys{/paperComment/#2}{##1/.initial={}}%
    }%
  \pgfqkeys{/paperComment/#2}{#1}%
}

%%% Print Loaded values
\newcommand{\printSection}[2][]{%
    \paragraph{#1}\hfill\par
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/paperComment/#2/#1}\par
}

\begin{document}

\initSLR[sch={Comments,Examples,Pros,Cons,Motivation,Focus}]

\section{The Schema is in the correct command}

\commentSch

\section{Expected Usage}
\PaperComment[Pros={The pros of pgfkeysToNotWork},
   Cons={The cons of pgfkeysToNotWork}
]{pgfkeysToNotWork}

\section{Dynamic is not Working}
\printSection[Cons]{pgfkeysToNotWork}
\printSection[Pros]{pgfkeysToNotWork}

\end{document}
```

[image]